# PL/SQL developer returns question marks instead of special characters

Tags: sql, oracle, character-encoding, nls

Hi im having a problem with PL/SQL Developer only returning question marks,
Its happens all the time unless i connect to another server through dblink, then it is able to return Danish letters or special characters like '£'. But whenever i run SQL locally it will not.

Also i can't compile stored procedures containing these letters so for example

```
selecet * from some_table where column like 'øæå' 

becomes **selecet * from some_table where column like '???'** after compile

a simple select 'åøæ' from dual also just returns ???
```

I have tried to search this site for answers since quite a few seems to have similar problems. but none of the answers seems to work.

Also its just on my workstation this problem exist, my colleagues don't have this problem, niether does my virtual machine. All run the same OS and have the same settings as far as we can see.

The machine is running windows 8, (codepage 850)
NLS settings

```
"PARAMETER";"VALUE";"CON_ID"
"NLS_LANGUAGE";"AMERICAN";"0"
"NLS_TERRITORY";"AMERICA";"0"
"NLS_CURRENCY";"$";"0"
"NLS_ISO_CURRENCY";"AMERICA";"0"
"NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS";".,";"0"
"NLS_CALENDAR";"GREGORIAN";"0"
"NLS_DATE_FORMAT";"DD-MON-RR";"0"
"NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE";"AMERICAN";"0"
"NLS_CHARACTERSET";"WE8ISO8859P15";"0"
"NLS_SORT";"BINARY";"0"
"NLS_TIME_FORMAT";"HH.MI.SSXFF AM";"0"
"NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT";"DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM";"0"
"NLS_TIME_TZ_FORMAT";"HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR";"0"
"NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT";"DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR";"0"
"NLS_DUAL_CURRENCY";"$";"0"
"NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET";"AL16UTF16";"0"
"NLS_COMP";"BINARY";"0"
"NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS";"BYTE";"0"
"NLS_NCHAR_CONV_EXCP";"FALSE";"0"
```

And if i look in regedit. Key_oraClient11g_home1 folder i get
NLS_lang AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8ISO8859P1

The difference from WE8ISO8859P1 to WE8ISO8859P15 should be minor. and changing WE8ISO8859P1 to WE8ISO8859P15 in regedit doesnt fix the problem.

Changing nls session language to =Danish, also doesn't fix the problem, does however change date to danish (from May => Maj, March => Marts etc.)

For anyone taking time to read and answer this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47587025/paste-chinese-symbols-to-oracle-db/47588652#47588652

Comment: Your title says PL/SQL Developer, but the question refers to SQL Developer - they are different clients, so which is it? (If SQL Developer, go to Tools->Preferences->Environment and check the encoding setting there too.)

Comment: Check if you have NLS_LANG defined in the environment. Open Command Prompt and enter SET. Environment overrides Registry. Also, check whether the Registry key for the client exists in HKEY_CURRENT_USER (usually should not).